# How can i get the different time with jquery when add the new <tr>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

I use jQuery to add new `<tr>` line, i need to show current time of the click but it shows duplicate time like this 
[image]

This is my code

```
<button type="button" class="add_line" id="add_line">+ Add More</button>
                <table class="tbl_add" style="width: 40%; font-size: 16px; ">
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="7">Add new code <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $code->id;?>"></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Date</td>
                        <td>No.Doc</td>
                        <td>Receive</td>
                        <td>Issue</td>
                        <td>Balance</td>
                        <td>Reference</td>
                        <td>Del</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

```
<script>
  var i=1;
  var t = '<?php echo date("H:i:s", time());?>';
  $("#add_line").on('click',function(){
    var data="<tr><input type='hidden' id='count' name='count' value='"+i+"'>"+
                " <td><input type='text' id='time_"+i+"' name='time_"+i+"' class='frm_text' value='"+t+"' readonly/><input type='text' id='dt_"+i+"' name='dt_"+i+"' class='frm_text' value='<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>' readonly/></td>" +
                " <td><input type='text' id='no_doc_"+i+"' name='no_doc_"+i+"' class='frm_text' placeholder='No.Doc' /></td>"+
                " <td><input type='text' id='receive_"+i+"' name='receive_"+i+"' class='frm_text' placeholder='Receive' /></td> "+
                " <td><input type='text' id='issue_"+i+"' name='issue_"+i+"' class='frm_text' placeholder='Issue' /></td> "+
                " <td><input type='text' id='balance_"+i+"' name='balance_"+i+"' class='frm_text' placeholder='Balance'/></td> " +
                " <td><input type='text' id='ref_"+i+"' name='ref_"+i+"' class='frm_text_full' placeholder='Ref.Project' /></td>"+ 
                " <td><a id='btnDelete' class='btnDelete'><img src='<?php echo site_url().'images/minus.png';?>' width='20px' height='20px' ></a></td></tr>";
        $('.tbl_add').append(data);
        i++;
});

  $(".tbl_add").on('click','.btnDelete',function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();

        });
</script>
```

How can i get the different time, please help me.

Comment: Get time and date using javascript, not PHP which is server side script... Or request each time server to get new time because depending user local time, javascript could give unexpected behaviour

Comment: You need to re-generate the date on every click... explained it on my answer :-)

Comment: @RonenCypis  Where the code you edit?

Comment: Didn't touch the code... just the explanation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happen is you are getting the date but each time you add the new table row then its not getting the current date and time , it does get the date and time stored in the variable when that page was loaded. so what you have to do is you have to create a function which can return you current date and time when you are about to add a new row in the table.

In your case what happen is its store the date and time once only when you run the code.

please check my code for more explanation.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body style="margin-bottom: 100px;">
        <button type="button" class="add_line" id="add_line">+ Add More</button>
        <table class="tbl_add" style="width: 40%; font-size: 16px; ">
            <tr>
                <td>Date</td>
                <td>No.Doc</td>
                <td>Receive</td>
                <td>Issue</td>
                <td>Balance</td>
                <td>Reference</td>
                <td>Del</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var i = 1;

            //var current_time = new Date(); 

            function getCurrentDateTime(){
                var currentdate = new Date(); 
                    var datetime = currentdate.getDate() + "/"
                        + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
                        + currentdate.getFullYear() + " "  
                        + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
                        + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
                        + currentdate.getSeconds();

                return datetime;
            }

            $("#add_line").on('click',function(){

                var date_time = getCurrentDateTime();

                var data="<tr><input type='hidden' id='count' name='count' value='"+i+"'>"+
                        " <td><input type='text' id='time_"+i+"' name='time_"+i+"' class='frm_text' value='"+date_time+"' readonly/><input type='text' id='dt_"+i+"' name='dt_"+i+"' class='frm_text' value='<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>' readonly/></td>" +
                        " <td><input type='text' id='no_doc_"+i+"' name='no_doc_"+i+"' class='frm_text' placeholder='No.Doc' /></td>"+
                        " <td><input type='text' id='receive_"+i+"' name='receive_"+i+"' class='frm_text' placeholder='Receive' /></td> "+
                        " <td><input type='text' id='issue_"+i+"' name='issue_"+i+"' class='frm_text' placeholder='Issue' /></td> "+
                        " <td><input type='text' id='balance_"+i+"' name='balance_"+i+"' class='frm_text' placeholder='Balance'/></td> " +
                        " <td><input type='text' id='ref_"+i+"' name='ref_"+i+"' class='frm_text_full' placeholder='Ref.Project' /></td>"+ 
                        " <td><a id='btnDelete' class='btnDelete'><img src='<?php echo site_url().'images/minus.png';?>' width='20px' height='20px' ></a></td></tr>";
                $('.tbl_add').append(data);
                i++;
            });

            $(".tbl_add").on('click','.btnDelete',function(){
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Let me know if you dont understand anywhere.

Comment: Your `input`'s value is still the PHP stuff... @Punit Gajjar

Answer (score 3):

You have to `take time every new click`, so just change your code with following :-

```
<script>
    var i=1;
    $("#add_line").on('click',function(){

        var dt  = new Date();
        var t   = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();

        var data="<tr><input type='hidden' id='count' name='count' value='"+i+"'>"+
                    " <td><input type='text' id='time_"+i+"' name='time_"+i+"' class='frm_text' value='"+t+"' readonly/><input type='text' id='dt_"+i+"' name='dt_"+i+"' class='frm_text' value='<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>' readonly/></td>" +
                    " <td><input type='text' id='no_doc_"+i+"' name='no_doc_"+i+"' class='frm_text' placeholder='No.Doc' /></td>"+
                    " <td><input type='text' id='receive_"+i+"' name='receive_"+i+"' class='frm_text' placeholder='Receive' /></td> "+
                    " <td><input type='text' id='issue_"+i+"' name='issue_"+i+"' class='frm_text' placeholder='Issue' /></td> "+
                    " <td><input type='text' id='balance_"+i+"' name='balance_"+i+"' class='frm_text' placeholder='Balance'/></td> " +
                    " <td><input type='text' id='ref_"+i+"' name='ref_"+i+"' class='frm_text_full' placeholder='Ref.Project' /></td>"+ 
                    " <td><a id='btnDelete' class='btnDelete'><img src='<?php echo site_url().'images/minus.png';?>' width='20px' height='20px' ></a></td></tr>";
        $('.tbl_add').append(data);
        i++;
    });

    $(".tbl_add").on('click','.btnDelete',function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
</script>
```

It may help you.

Comment: @HarshSanghani you didn't change the value of the relevant `input`... it still has the php stuff...

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP code segments (`php echo date("H:i:s", time());` and `php echo date("Y-m-d");`) run only once when the page is loaded, and from then on, the `t` var and the string date in your `var data` holds that date and never change....

You need to generate new date value on every click like so:

```
var t = new Date();
```

and then You can do whatever you want with it like so:

```
var dateValue = t.getFullYear() + '-' + (t.getMonth()+1) + '-' + t.getDate();
// will look like: 2015-12-24
```

For additional options you have with the `Date` object, read the [Javascript Date Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Answer (score 1):

use 
`var t = new Date(); // for current time`
and use it inside click function.

```
<script>
  var i=1;
  $("#add_line").on('click',function(){
    var t = new Date(); // for current time
    var data="<tr><input type='hidden' id='count' name='count' value='"+i+"'>"+
                " <td><input type='text' id='time_"+i+"' name='time_"+i+"' class='frm_text' value='"+t+"' readonly/><input type='text' id='dt_"+i+"' name='dt_"+i+"' class='frm_text' value='<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>' readonly/></td>" +
                " <td><input type='text' id='no_doc_"+i+"' name='no_doc_"+i+"' class='frm_text' placeholder='No.Doc' /></td>"+
                " <td><input type='text' id='receive_"+i+"' name='receive_"+i+"' class='frm_text' placeholder='Receive' /></td> "+
                " <td><input type='text' id='issue_"+i+"' name='issue_"+i+"' class='frm_text' placeholder='Issue' /></td> "+
                " <td><input type='text' id='balance_"+i+"' name='balance_"+i+"' class='frm_text' placeholder='Balance'/></td> " +
                " <td><input type='text' id='ref_"+i+"' name='ref_"+i+"' class='frm_text_full' placeholder='Ref.Project' /></td>"+ 
                " <td><a id='btnDelete' class='btnDelete'><img src='<?php echo site_url().'images/minus.png';?>' width='20px' height='20px' ></a></td></tr>";
        $('.tbl_add').append(data);
        i++;
});

  $(".tbl_add").on('click','.btnDelete',function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();

        });
</script>
```

Comment: It's working but if i want to show the only time how can i do it?